# NSData contentsOfURL Returns Nil?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I have the following code

```
import Foundation

let url = NSURL(string: copiedURL)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
print("\(data)")
let image2 = UIImage(data: data!)
```

When I build and run, I get the following error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` referring to

```
let image2 = UIImage(data: data!)
```

I tried to modify my `Info.plist` with the following

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

But the error is still there. Is there any more possible solutions I can try?

Comment: Does your URL points to a valid image?

Comment: Don't use `contentsOfURL:` for network requests.

Comment: We need to see the code before this, specifically what `copiedURL` is and how you arrived at it. Are you trying to load an image that's on the local file on the system or is it on a network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of possibilities here.

1. The copiedURL is not being properly converted to a NSURL
2. The NSURL is not being converted to NSData
3. The image is unable to load the data

Try the following:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: copiedURL) {
    print(url)
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        print(data)
        let image2 = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```

It's almost never a good idea to force unwrap something (!), instead use `guard` or `if let` to unwrap and thus be able to handle the nil condition.

Refer to: [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift) for how to properly download images.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: copiedURL) {
   if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
   print("\(data)")
   let image2 = UIImage(data: data)
   }
}
```

If `copiedURL` has valid image you will get it, otherwise atleast your app will not crash.